Spark hanging on Kotlin mapping function
I have a spark job that is running into some performance problems and I have identified a handful of improvements that can be made to optimize and get the application working as expected. This question is more for my understanding to know if I did not have the performance improvements available, how "could" I make my current situation work? I'd like a deeper understanding of spark config and how it could resolve the problem with no code changes.
In the code, we are reading in a parquet file and then converting it to a Kotlin list
val df = spark.read().parquet(filepath)

val myList = df.collectAsList()

return try {
   myList.map { row ->
      // Creates 3 Kotlin objects per row
   }
}

My understanding of this is spark is utilizing the executors for the parquet file read, but when converted to the Kotlin list, all work done on the myList is now executed on the Driver and none of the executors. Is this correct?
If that's true, when the job "hangs" with this implementation with no errors, my mind goes to memory issues, possibly garbage collection issues given the amount of objects being created while iterating through the list. I've tried the following to try and force this implementation to work, but it was not successful
- spark.driver.memory - 84G - original 12G
- spark.driver.maxResultSize - 9G - original not set

I thought increasing the memory of the driver itself would solve the issue but it did not, so now I'm looking more into GC of which I see these logs (note: these logs print for ~15 minutes, then no logs ever print again, even is the job is still technically running for hours past)
[GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: ...]]

So my next possibility is tuning garbage collection but really no idea where to start there, or if this issue is even GC related

if you don't really need all the data locally in one go you could try toLocalIterator instead (max partition size memory instead of all the data collectively)
